# sharepoint 2013 autohosted -upgrade package

Tags: upgrade, office-365

Hello i started to developing sharepoint 2013 on my office 365 account- autohosted apps.
And it looks that every small change in project in visual studio and deploying it to online account deletes everything.i mean that entries in lists are deleted , database is cleared.

I wonder if is there a way to avoid this.
i would like that f.e i have a list in my app. and after developing it i add some items.
Then i would like to add one column to this list. how to do this without deleting all content.

The same with database. F.e i have a table with two columns and a lot of data in it.
Then i would like to add one column. how to do this without deleting every content in database(without deploying package once more)
any ideas?
best regards